# Is it possible to undo a rollback?

Tags: sql, postgresql

I was fiddling around in a table testing some inserts and updates.

I always started my commands with a `BEGIN;` and when I saw the results, I would run a `ROLLBACK;` afterwards.

I accidentally hit F5 twice with `ROLLBACK;` highlighted, and it rolled back to being empty.

Is there a way to undo the `ROLLBACK;`?

Edit: as it turns out, this didn't play out as I'd thought. I didn't hit F5 twice causing some double-rollback, it just happened that there was a delete being run at the same time as I was interacting with the DB and nobody had informed me. Still, I'll keep this around for now to show that there is seemingly no way to undo a rollback.

Comment: I don't believe so 
https://www.tutorialspoint.com/postgresql/postgresql_transactions.htm

Comment: Thanks for the resource. Add it as an answer and I'll hit the checkmark! Turns out this was an expected (but uncommunicated) deletion, so it apparently wasn't me, haha. Either way, good to know for the future.

Comment: Follow this link : [tutorialspoint.com/postgresql/postgresql_transactions.htm](http://tutorialspoint.com/postgresql/postgresql_transactions.htm)

Comment: Done! That took me a while :D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to @visch for the answer:

> I don't believe so tutorialspoint.com/postgresql/postgresql_transactions.htm

Edit: to provide more context and make everyone happy, you can't undo a rollback because the transaction is effectively blown away in the following circumstances:

1. An error within the DB occurs
2. The connection is lost
3. Commit is run
4. Rollback is run

So once any of those conditions are met, the transaction is wiped - no records are stored of transactions because that's the whole point

Comment: A reference to an off-site resource is not an answer. You should quote the relevant text from that link in the answer itself.

Comment: I would normally, but the evidence in this case is the specific absence of relevant text, so that doesn't work.

Comment: Then this really isn't a good answer, and *should* be deleted.

Comment: I've changed the answer to hopefully make everyone happy. It's not directly stated anywhere in the link, but this is what I've gathered from reading it and a few other sources.